# mnt/sdb1 is not ready or present press "s"to skip "M"

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and all was well until a recent update mess things up. Now when I boot up it get stuck at

```
 mnt/sdb1 is not ready or present press s to  skip M to manually repair
```

plus another choice. If I select `M` you get to a dead end and have to reboot. I usually skip to boot. The other choice gets me to the boot screen where you can choose Ubuntu and other choice. Right next to `U` the Ubuntu choice I see `*Ubuntu` that is very strange . Can you help? I don't want to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have removed your external hard disk. /dev/sda is for internal hard disk and /dev/sdb is for external hard disk. By update, I take it you have upgraded the system to Ubuntu 14.04? If not please post the Ubuntu version that you are running. That can be done by using

`cat /etc/lsb-release`

Also please provide the output of

`sudo blkid`